# How to use react native elements slider with two marker?

Tags: react-native, slider

Hello i'm new on react native. I am using react native elements slider in my project but want to select range with two marker. It is working with one marker.

Here is my code :

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}>
          <Slider
            style={{ width: '90%',marginLeft:20,marginRight:20 }}
            minimumValue={0}
            maximumValue={100}
            step={1}
            value={this.state.cost}
            onValueChange={cost => console.log(cost)}
          />
          <Text style={{marginLeft:20,marginRight:20}}>{this.state.cost}</Text>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

React Native Elements slider doesn't support multiple marker. However you can use [this](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider) library if you need multiple markers